# countvectorizer not able to detect , words

Tags: python, nlp, countvectorizer

```
final_vocab = {'Amazon',
'Big Bazaar',
'Brand Factory',
'Central',
'Cleartrip',
'Dominos',
'Flipkart',
'IRCTC',
'Lenskart',
'Lifestyle',
'MAX',
'MMT',
'More',
'Myntra'}
 
vect = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=final_vocab)
token_df = pd.DataFrame(vect.fit_transform(['Big Bazaar','Brand Factory']).todense(), columns=vect.get_feature_names())
```

[image]

why all output is zero ??? for Big Bazaar and brand factory values should come 1 ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CountVectorizer` is missing 2 things:

1. `ngram_range=(2,2)` as stated in the docs: `All values of n such such that min_n <= n <= max_n will be used`. This help `CountVectorizer` get 2 gram vector from the input (`Big Bazaar` instead of `['Big','Bazaar']`)
2. `lowercase=False` which means: `Convert all characters to lowercase before tokenizing`. This will make `Big Bazaar` and `Brand Factory` became lower case and thus can't be found in vocabulary. Setting to False will prevent that from happening.

Also, because you've provided a vocabulary to `CountVectorizer`, use `transform` instead of `fit_transform`

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

final_vocab = ['Amazon',
'Big Bazaar',
'Brand Factory',
'Central',
'Cleartrip',
'Dominos',
'Flipkart',
'IRCTC',
'Lenskart',
'Lifestyle',
'MAX',
'MMT',
'More',
'Myntra']
 
vect = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=final_vocab, ngram_range=(2, 2), lowercase=False)
token_df = pd.DataFrame(vect.transform(['Big Bazaar','Brand Factory']).todense(), columns=vect.get_feature_names())
```